# JavaScript mixin as a class

Tags: javascript, mixins

I found this technique to create a mixin:

```
let fooMixin = {
    foo() {console.log('foo')},
};

class A {
    bar() {console.log('bar')}
}

Object.assign(A.prototype, fooMixin);
```

however I would prefer to use `class` syntax also for the mixin.

I tried this:

```
class FooMixinClass {
    foo() {console.log('foo')}
}

class B {
    bar() {console.log('bar')}
}

Object.assign(B.prototype, FooMixinClass.prototype);

let b = new B();
b.bar();
b.foo();
```

but get this error:

> "bar"

> TypeError: b.foo is not a function. (In 'b.foo()', 'b.foo' is undefined)"

I would like to understand why it doesn't work, since inspecting `FooMixinClass.prototype` at runtime reveals an object almost identical to `fooMixin`.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a5ufjchz/

Comment: Why not use `extends` if you want to set the prototype of `B` to `FooMixinClass`?

Comment: @RandyCasburn because he doesn't want to set the prototype of `B` to `FooMixinClass` but basically to `B.prototype & FooMixinClass.prototype`. OP wants to add all the nice stuff from `FooMixinClass` onto the existing class `B` without changing the existing inheritance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would like to understand why it doesn't work, since inspecting `FooMixinClass.prototype` at runtime reveals an object almost identical to `fooMixin`.

The keyword is almost. Methods on a class are not `enumerable` and `Object.assign()` only copies properties that are `enumerable` and not inherited

A utility-function:

```js
class FooMixinClass {
  static foo() {
    console.log("foo, but static");
  }
  foo() {
    console.log('foo')
  }
}

class B {
  bar() {
    console.log('bar')
  }
}

function mixin(target, source) {
  // ignore the Function-properties
  const {name,length,prototype,...statics} = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(source);
  Object.defineProperties(target, statics);
  // console.log("static", statics);

  // ignore the constructor
  const {constructor,...proto} = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(source.prototype);
  Object.defineProperties(target.prototype, proto);
  // console.log("proto", proto);

  return target;
}

mixin(B, FooMixinClass);

let b = new B();
b.bar();
b.foo();
B.foo();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```